# Copying content of <code></code> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, tags, save

How can I save text in `<code></code>` tag as a html file?
I also want to write a name for this file in browser save file window.

Comment: This is what you are probably after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: want you create a snipper or literally a new page on a server?

Comment: -1. This question shows little thought and no research. You might consider looking at SO's "How to ask a good question" page at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I just want to save text in <code></code> tag on my own site as a html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit DTD file，and include "XXXX.DTD".If you can not edit DTD，you should study it.
follow as blow

```html
<!DOCTYPEnoteSYSTEM"note.dtd">
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don'tforgetmethisweekend!</body>
</note>
```